# PNG's alpha as a separate file?

Tags: html, png, alpha

Is there some way to use a grayscale or bitmap image as an alpha "channel" in HTML rather than save it as a transparent PNG?

I have about 12 variations of transparency patterns I need applied to about 200 images. I don't want to make 2400 images for every possible combination. I'd rather say "Use this image for transparency on that image."

This doesn't have to be compatible with older browsers as it will be for internal use. Can HTML5 do this?

Comment: All I know about is PNGs with transparency. I can't think of any other method other than flash.

Comment: You could also do the alpha merge in the server side, (eg, with ImageMagick) but that would depend on your server side scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with image masks. Currently only supported in Webkit browsers.

[**Read all about it**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-webkit-mask-image) .:.
**[And example usage.](http://css-tricks.com/webkit-image-wipes/)**

Comment: I *would* like it to be compatible with more than just Opera and Chrome. Is that the only way? I may have to resort to flash...

Comment: It may be possible to do on the server side, but that's out of my realm here.

Comment: That looks like that might work. I found a VB script that does that called ASPJpeg. I'll post back if it works.